Make my server listening on the TUN interface
I created a TUN interface on my Windows 11 machine and assigned it the IP address 10.11.12.13.
I need to bind a local server to listen on this interface and port 4000. My goal is to craft IP/TCP packets from scratch and direct them to this local server.
When I configure my server, it successfully binds to 10.11.12.13:4000. However, it seems that the system is actually binding it to the loopback interface rather than my TUN interface, as shown by this Wireshark capture:
Packets on the loopback interface
This is problematic because I cannot inject packets into the loopback interface, only into the TUN interface. Here is my routing table:
===========================================================================
Liste d'Interfaces
  8..........................Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
 95...........................TUN Tunnel
  3..........................VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  7..........................VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4
  6..........................VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
 17..........................VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
 26..........................TAP-Windows Adapter V9 for OpenVPN Connect
 23..........................Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 21..........................Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 11...........................Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX1650s 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201D2W)
 27...........................Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 33...........................Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 96..........................Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Table de routage
===========================================================================
Itinéraires actifs :
Destination réseau    Masque réseau  Adr. passerelle   Adr. interface Métrique
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.101     35
       10.11.12.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.11.12.13    261
      10.11.12.13  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.11.12.13    261
     10.11.12.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.11.12.13    261

Here is my TUN interface configuration:
Adapter TUN:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . :
Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : TUN Tunnel
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled. . . . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.11.12.13 (Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . . :
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . : Enabled

How can I ensure that my application is properly listening on the TUN interface and not on loopback?
How to reproduce (minimal example)
Step 1 - Create a simple Tun interface
First, create a TUN interface and associate the IP 10.11.12.13 with it. A simple way to do it is by using the following minimal Rust code (Note that I have the same problem with other implementation, in C language for example):
use std::{io};
use std::io::{Read};
use tun::platform::Device as TunDevice;
use tun::{Configuration, Layer};

fn create_tun_interface() -> std::io::Result<TunDevice> {
    let mut config = Configuration::default();

    // Configure the TUN interface
    config
        .address("10.11.12.13")
        .netmask("255.255.255.0")
        .up()
        .layer(Layer::L3)
        .name("TUN"); // Name of the TUN interface

    TunDevice::new(&config).map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, e.to_string()))
}

fn handle_tun_interface(mut dev: TunDevice) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 1504];
    let mut packet = Vec::with_capacity(1504);

    loop {
        // Read a packet from the TUN interface
        match dev.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(n) => {
                packet.clear();
                packet.extend_from_slice(&buf[..n]);

                for byte in &packet {
                    print!("{:02x} ", byte);
                }
                println!();

            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Failed to read from TUN device: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    match create_tun_interface() {
        Ok(dev) => {
            handle_tun_interface(dev);
        }
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Failed to create TUN interface: {}", e),
    }

}

Don't forget to add the tun dependency:
cargo add tun
Then build the program:
cargo build
Don't forget to copy the wintun.dll file to the folder of the executable file. You can download it from here:
https://www.wintun.net/
Then execute the .exe with administrator rights.
You should now see the TUN interface in the network interface list.
Step 2 - Start a server on 10.11.12.13:4000
A simple way to do it is by using python, in powershell (but any kind of server will do the job, and I also tried with other server types):
python3 -m http.server --bind 10.11.12.13 4000

At this moment, you can notice that the server is currently listening on 10.11.12.13:4000 with a simple
netstat /a

Step 3 - Send packets to the server
For example, by using telnet, or even curl:
curl 10.11.12.13:4000

This works!
Step 4 - Notice the problem: server is listening on loopback and not TUN
Open wireshark, and try to capture packets on the TUN interface.
You will notice that no packets to 10.11.12.13:4000 are displayed, even if you replay the curl command.
Now, change the interface in Wireshark, and attach on loopback.
You can now see the packets.
This is not the behavior I expect, because I am actually unable to craft packets to the server as any packet injected on TUN will not be interpreted by the server

Please [edit] your question and copy&paste text as text and format it as a code block. Are you sending and receiving the packets on the same system? I suggest to use two systems.

I made some edits and added information about the interface configuration. Yes, the packets are sent and received on the same system. There is no other device involved, as this is not my goal—I am trying to create a proof of concept for using a VPN client. Would using two systems help me understand what is wrong?

Are you using the TUN interface as intended, by opening its "backend" with some software? Because if you aren't, you won't see any traffic in it with Wireshark.

Yes, I have a software running with the admin right used to open the TUN interface and read / write packets on it. I am able to correctly read and inject the packets (and I am able to see these packets in Wireshark too, on the TUN interface)

Adding a minimal reproducible example of all involved programs to your question might help to understand what exactly you are doing.

Thank you, I have edited the post to add a minimal reproducible example

By using curl, you are not using the TUN adapter. That Rust code you show is what has to inject those TCP packets.

Actually, curl should "use it" because of the routing rule in the routing table. Also, If I try to curl 10.11.12.9:4000 (another address in the range, that is NOT the address of the interface), I am able to see the packets in wireshark and catch them in my software.

Another way of describing the problem is : If I inject packets through the Rust program to the destination 10.11.12.13:4000 they never reach the server, as the server is actually listening on loopback and not on TUN

This will usually happen when sending packets to the machine's own addresses – all local addresses go through internal loopback (i.e. it is not the job of individual NIC drivers to reflect them back).
You've configured the TUN interface with a /24, so pick a differen address (e.g. 10.11.12.99) and use that as the fake source for your injected packets via TUN.

Awesome, you're right, this works. As the system is using the interface IP address when applications reach the server, this could not work. But by choosing a different source IP address when injecting, this works as expected. Thank you!
